# Computer Memory Configuration

Tags: memory, ddr3, dual-channel, sandy-bridge

So I currently have 4x 4GB Dimms of 1600Mhz memory (DDR3) in my computer, however one dimm has went bad.

Now, my understanding is that they are dual-channel, which means they are ment to run in pairs.

Is it better to drop to 2x 4GB Dimms for a total of 8GB of memory (preserving dual-channel)

or; go 3x 4GB Dimms for 12GB of memory, however i loose the dual-channel advantage, right?

Thanks SuperUser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you're running. If the software you use gobbles up a lot of RAM, you'll be better off with the three good DIMMs. But if you never use the extra 4 GB, you might technically be better off removing the third DIMM; but chances are, [you would be hard-pressed to notice the difference between single-channel and dual-channel mode in most games and consumer software.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Performance)

That said, most RAM comes with a lifetime warranty these days. I'd just RMA the bad DIMM. Or, if it isn't under warranty for some reason, I'd either live with 12 GB or pony up the 20 bucks to buy a replacement.

Comment: The difference between dual and single channel isn't noticable under a lot of workloads - so you may be okay.

Comment: Thanks; Thats essentially what I plan to do; just wondered if 8GB Dualchannel or 12GB is better in the meantime.   Thanks again

Comment: No problem...in that case, I'd definitely just leave it with 12 GB until you get the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

all three good DIMMS will register and work albeit one pair will function in dual channel mode while the third dIMM will run under single channel under Intel FastMemory.